# No question titles for user's answers in the Activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, activity

[image]

Questions are fine.

Comment: Same report on Meta SO: [The “Answers” card on the Activity page does not show any titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414799/8839059)

Comment: This bug was introduced by a change in our model. We're on it!

Comment: Now also reported here: [New responsive Activity page](/a/374107/289905).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been fixed

> answer titles blank?
> sorry for the regression
> back to normal now